# Problem resolving a generic repository with Entity Framework and a Castle Windsor container

Tags: frameworks, repository, entity, generics, inversion-of-control

I'm working in a generic repository implementarion with [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) v4, and the repository must be resolved by a [Windsor container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Project#Features).

First the interface,

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    T Find(int key)
}
```

Then a concrete class implements the interface

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;
}
```

So I need `_objectSet` to do stuff like this in the previous class,

```
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }
```

And now the problem, as you can see, I'm using a Entity Framework interface like `IObjectSet` to do the work, but this type requires a constraint for the T generic type "where T: class".

That constraint is causing an exception when Windsor tries to resolve its concrete type. The Windsor configuration look like this.

```
<castle>
    <components>
        <component id="LVRepository"
                   service="Repository.Infraestructure.IRepository`1, Repository"
                   type="Repository.Infraestructure.Repository`1, Repository"
                   lifestyle="transient">
        </component>
    </components>
</castle>
```

The container resolves code:

```
IRepository<Product> productsRep =_container.Resolve<IRepository<Product>>();
```

Now the exception I'm getting:

```
System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'T', on 'Repository.Infraestructure.Repository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'T', on 'Repository.Infraestructure.Repository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.
```

If I remove the constraint in the concrete class and the dependency on IObjectSet (if I don't do it, I get a compile error) everything works FINE, so I don't think it is a container issue, but
`IObjectSet` is a MUST in the implementation.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was a long time ago, but one work around is to put the same constraint on your interface.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
```